# What would countries be like after nuclear war?

Tags: warfare, nuclear-weapons

So there is a nuclear war between the Soviet Union and the United States Of America in 2068. All countries with nukes fire at their enemies. The countries of China, the USA, USSR, the EU ( with Britain still in it) fire about 42,000 nukes. 3,000 megatons were launched during the war.

403 megatons were fires into the USA, killing 290 million, Canada was hit with 260 megatons, killing 30 million people, 
EU got 390 megatons, killing 460 million, China gets 402 megatons killing 900 million, and finally USSR gets hit with 409 megatons and killed 300 million people( their population was 323 million). Japan and N/S Korea are both also hit with about 100 megatons killing 100 million

Most of the bombs land in the Northern hemisphere, but Australia and New Zealand are both also hit with 20 megatons each killing 25 million. Nucear winter sets into the northern hemisphere, not completely killing all plant life but it makes farming harder. In the Southern Hemisphere, life is easier than in the north, but the winds carry radioactive materials down into the south killing some of their crops. Cancer becomes more common as their is no longer and Ozone layer.

My question is, in the countries that got hit, what would most likely happen in the next years?

My question is, what will likely happen to the countries society, if it remains.

Comment: Happen to societies? Happen to politics? Happen to economies? Happen to food production? Life expectancy? Infant mortality? Food transport to the remaining cities? Industrial production? Taxes? Reconstruction spending? Cleanup and remediation? Climatological patterns and weather? This question seems very broad. Whole books have been written on tiny slices of this topic. Perhaps a narrower scope would be more appropriate?

Comment: It looks like you might have created two accounts. [See here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) if you'd like to merge them.

Comment: You might want to watch [Threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threads). I think it's fully available on youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, give a look at Siria and see how they have been faring after such a prolonged civil war.

Most of the population in those countries will start migrating South as refugees, seeking entrance in countries of South and Central America, Africa, and basically any island country.

These refugees will probably face the same problems refugees face today, with the added problem of being seem by what remains of the global community as bringers of doom. Many countries will probably deny them entrance, instead sending some token humanitarian help.

Milicias will sprout all around on the afflicted countries, fighting for any piece of land that isn't irradiated. Many will receive financing of foreing countries, any that start becoming too troublesome will be swiftly eliminated.

Surviving Countries will probably deploy troops on the destroyed countries for "humanitarian aid", try to rescue any surviving leadership, kill eventual local warlords, and try to set up camps.

You will probably see Socialist governements sprouting all around as the market collapse and the lack of resources force the governments into more and more authoritarian paths.

Food will soon become a problem as the nuclear winter sets in, but some governements can start massive hidroponic projects to produce enough food for their populations. Many surviving governments will collapse because of lack of food.